Which Technology and software used to create this book?
This is a sample page of "GCSE physics, third edition, Tom duncan 1986, 1987, 1995"
https://ibb.co/kqgSSNR
I like the design of this book in general. Could you guess which offset printing technology those used for printing and also in that decades (80's and 90's) which computer software used to for inserting text and design especially for this kind of books? Thanks

Hard to tell. Offset technology wasn't really that different back then, but layout software was just in it's infancy and many processes were still analog. But it doesn't really matter. You can't make books that way anymore anyway. Today a book like this would often be made in Adobe InDesign.

There was more variation in technologies used when we worked in the physical/analog world. Mainly because copying of digital goods is so easy. But also partially because there is less talented toolmakers for a digital world. Nearly everybody can when pressed design a jig and execute on it. Mainly because we have more practical experience with physical items. Not that many people can program the equivalent tool.

It's not possible to know exactly how a layout was created 50-60 years ago.
All one can do is correlate the general timeframe with the development and proliferation of technology.

The 1980s would have been hand stripped and typeset photo-mechanicals (all by hand, software wasn't a thing until roughly 1987).
The 1990s could have been Photoshop, Illustrator, QuarkXpress. Post ~1995, everything would have been digital.
Today, It would be InDesign, Photoshop, and Illustrator in most cases. Perhaps Adobe Framemaker for reference and text books. Although QuarkXpress is still a very viable package, just not as proliferate today as it was in the 90s - post release of Adobe Indesign.

All this being posted, it is still very possible to use 1980 techniques today, they just aren't common due to speed and the benefits of easy editing technology allows. It is also possible to use alternative software than what is listed here. Just because Adobe products are the market leader and most common, they don't have to be used exclusively. Things like Gimp, Inkscape Scribus can often be used.
This question is a bit like asking "What oven baked this cake in 1980?" You can guess based on market leaders and abilities at a given time, but there's no real way to know for certain. That is, unless one had a hand in the baking.

A guess: The layout was made manually by pasting on a light table text blocks, black graphic items, and placeholders of photos and colored items. The backlight made possible to have a guide grid.
Text blocks were ordered from a phototypesetter operator. He couldn't create full layouts, but well-typeset text blocks came out as high resolution photos on a partially transparent material.
Photos and colored items met the layout in print plate preparation where color separated print plates were made. That happens still in offset prints, but digital print machines do not need print plates.
Transforming the accepted manuscript to a book needed in old days an army of highly skilled artisans, everyone was the master of his step in the process. Typesetting was computerized first. In the middle of 1970's computer font based phototypesetting  became mainstream (earlier there were phototypesetters with fonts stored on transparent film). The typesetter used a machine which was based on a minicomputer and generated the wanted text blocks as high resolution photos. But as long as the layout making and print preparation was a form of handcrafting; also, metal type and typesetting based on it was used.
Handcrafting vanished gradually when the speed and cost efficiency of computer based designing and printing forced book producers to either adapt the new methods or be kicked out of business. I know several book press artisans and typesetters who suddenly found in the beginning of 1990's they had no job. Some of them were creative enough to be able to continue as independent contractors who had their own computers and DTP software. Others had to start to do something else.

Thank you for great explanation.
